# when page loads styles are applying fine however as am using UPDATE Panel after postback (means on click of any button) styles are disappear

Tags: jquery, asp.net

when page loads styles are applying fine however as am using UPDATE Panel after postback (means on click of any button) styles are disappear , i searched in net there they mentioned after update pannel load complete we should the apply styels again.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function() {

                        $(".formstyle").jqTransform();
                    });
</script>

    <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlArtist" CssClass="formstyle" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddlArtist_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            <p class="maintext"><asp:Literal ID="ltrArtistDesc" runat="server"></asp:Literal></p>
            </ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is because update panel not reload you `Jquery` code after post-back.Please use given code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        $(".formstyle").jqTransform();
    });
 </script>
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

function pageLoad()
 {

RebindMyStuff();

```
    }

    function RebindMyStuff() {

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(function () {

                $(".formstyle").jqTransform();

            });

        });
```

}